# Schema Registry read-only copy

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

we have 2 different Data-centers (DC-A and DC-B) with no connectivity between them. Actually only inbound traffic is allowed to DC-B from DC-A. we have schema-registry setup in DC-A, and we would like to get a replica running in DC-B.

What are the options? Can I setup a new instance in DC-B with read-only mode and have schemas topic replicated from DC-A (since inbound replication is allowed)? We would never create new schemas in DC-B, all we need is access to schemas in DC-A.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible, although likely not a preferred setup. If I understand you correctly, you have two DCs with no connectivity outside of DC-B allows inbound traffic from DC-A. Do you have a Kafka cluster in DC-B? I'm assuming you do, since you talked about replication.

If so, you can have two "separate" schema registries but with one essentially being a replica in DC-B. I haven't tried this out yet but it should work and would be easily testable with Docker.

See this architecture diagram for how it could work:
[image: architecture diagram]

The primary schema registry would be set up as normal against Kafka A. You would use a replicator (Confluent Replicator, MirrorMaker, etc) to copy the `_schemas` topic to Kafka B. Note that it would be recommended to run the replicator in DC B, but it sounds like that would not be possible with your networking setup.

You would then set up a second schema registry running against Kafka B, which will read from the `_schemas` topic on Kafka B. You can then set the schema registry in DC B to `READONLY` mode. If READONLY mode doesn't update when new schemas are registered, you could set `master.eligibility` to false on the DC B schema registry and it would error when trying to create new schemas since it has no ties to the primary schema registry.

Some resources:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/multidc.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#mode

Comment: Awesome Thanks! I was not sure if the READONLY mode is allowed on a schema-registry instance such that no writes are allowed. I will try this week.